# Apache Serving Wrong Certificate

Tags: apache, ssl

I have two virtual hosts with each its own certificate. When accessing the one virtualhost it serves the wrong certificate. the certifate from the other host has an different alternate name in the certificate definitions file.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how are you're virtualhosts configured. you need to:

#### enable Name based virtualhosting

this is needed only for apache < 2.3.11

usually it's done in apache main configuration file

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

#### Create Virtualhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.domain1.com
# SSl configuration for domain1
....
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.domain2.com
# SSl configuration for domain2
....
</VirtualHost>
```

Keep in mind that if you're using the same IP for the 2 Virtualhosts, Apache will use SNI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication and will pass the host it will be going to connect to during the TLS negotiation.

That means that you'll not be able to test it using a simple

```
openssl -connect www.domain2.com:443 
#you will get domain1 certificate
```

you will need to use

```
openssl -connect www.domain2.com:443 --servername www.domain2.com 
#you will get domain1 certificate
```

Comment: Apache 2.4 says AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release

Comment: Yep, but it is still working now, and the question doesn't provide the apache version

Comment: Ok, you can edit your answer mentioning what I brought up, and I'll vote up ;)